# Remote Image is not loading. No value for profilePic JSONException

Tags: android, json

In jsone I receive :

`"profilePic":"http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/nat.jpg","image":"\/images\/1491410855.JPG"`

How to convert it to normal URL to set in an ImageView by using `setImageUrl()`?

Comment: You should use a library like Picasso to set the image on an imageview

Comment: That is a normal URL with escape characters... Fix the server that generates that JSON

Comment: I had tried using ` .replaceAll("\\\\", "") ` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

However you print / gather that JSON is not correct since you are seeing escape characters.

For example, this [source](http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json)

```
{
    "feed": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "National Geographic Channel",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
            "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },
```

Try using Volley `JsonObjectRequest`

Then,

```
JSONArray feed = response.getJSONArray("feed");
for (int i = 0; i < feed.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject feedObj = feed.getJSONObjet(i);
    String profilePic = feedObj.getString("profilePic");
    // Picasso.load(profilePic).into(imageView); // for example
}
```

[See tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/)